# UIImage imageWithData leak (GCD)

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, uiimage, nsautoreleasepool, grand-central-dispatch

Hi I am getting a reported leak from Instrument with the following code.

```
dispatch_async(requestQueue, ^{

        NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest
                                                  options:0
                                                    error:&error];
        if (error != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);

            [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[error localizedDescription]
                                         message:[error localizedFailureReason]
                                        delegate:nil
                               cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil)
                               otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease] show];
            return;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            if (delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageRequestDone:)])              
            {
                [delegate imageRequestDone:image];
            }
        });
    });
```

Leaks reports that my image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData] leaks, any ideas why?
Do I need to a NSAutoreleasePool for the autoreleased UIImage object?

Btw, If its matter, I declared __block UIImage *image = nil; above because I check for the image in an ImageCache before entering the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't released your queue: `dispatch_release(requestQueue);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice. It didn't help though. But when I came back home a ran my code on my own computer instruments didn't report the leak? Maybe a bug in Instruments? After a while at work I couldn't run leaks at all, anyone else got the same problems? The leak "track" became yellow.